# Starting the Report Manager (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services, reportmanager

I am following this Microsoft tutorial http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c962b0ff-ce8a-4742-8262-dc730901afcf for SSRS and I am having trouble starting the report manager,

The tutorial says to type in the computer name followed by reports in Internet Explorer, i.e. 'http:compname/reports' but I don't know why it won't let me access it,

Any help would be appreciated,

Nick

Comment: What error are you getting? What url are you using? (`http:compname/reports' is missing a couple of slashes.) Are you trying this from the local machine? Have you tried it from a remote machine?

Comment: Sorry the exact url I am using is http://spr002/reports. Just says "This page can't be displayed". Dont know if I have to do something before I type the URL in... No I have only tried this from my local machine. @JamieF

Comment: Have you installed and configured SSRS? the link you provided requires are running instance of SSRS already. Presumably, you aren't using SharePoint integration, so this link may help you with configuration: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156305.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, have you properly configured the report server? If not, follow this tutorial (make sure SSRS service is running beforehand):

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/12/tutorials/26/tutorials/4600/getting-started-with-ssrs-part-4-configuring-sql-server-reporting-services-in-windows-server-2008.aspx

After that, you will probably run into 'access denied' problem - the solution is available here:

http://blog.davyknuysen.be/2009/09/11/administrator-has-no-access-to-the-report-manager-sql2008-r2-and-windows7vista/

Comment: Just want to point out that both of those links are dead. This is why it is important to put the pertinent details from links into answers. This answer is useless without them.

Answer (score 0):

After installing SSRS on to a Window 2012 R2 server, I was able to open the report browser from the server but, I was not able to open the report browser from a remote machine ... It said "This page can't be displayed" ... After hours of research, I realized that may be my firewall was blocking port 80 (I know right?) ... Suffice to say, it was blocking port 80!!!

Answer: Create a rule in "Windows Firewall with Advnace Security" to allow port 80 resquests.

Hope this helps